# Using two WebBrowsers on codename one (layout management)

Tags: layout, browser, codenameone

I want to display two webbrowsers on one screen, the first show an URL and the second show a custom banner. 
I tried with a table layout to display two rows, and set the weight on 80% for the first and 20% for the second. But when I run the app only the first shows up, and cover 100% of the height

This is what I want:
[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this codes
it should solve

```
protected void beforePage(Form f) {

    f.setScrollableY(false);
    TableLayout.Constraint c1 = new TableLayout.Constraint();
    c1.setHeightPercentage(80);
    c1.setWidthPercentage(100);
    TableLayout.Constraint c2 = new TableLayout.Constraint();
    c2.setHeightPercentage(20);
    c2.setWidthPercentage(100);

    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.setURL("http://www.facebook.com");

    WebBrowser browser2 = new WebBrowser();
      browser2.setURL("http://www.google.com");
    f.setLayout(new TableLayout(2, 1));
    f.addComponent(c1, browser);
    f.addComponent(c2, browser2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible

1. create tablelayout with column 1 and row 2
2. add first webbrowser and set its height to 80 %
3. and add second and set 20%

I hope it will help

Comment: that´s what I did. But the first webbrowser  fill the 100 % of the screen, even when was set to cover 80%

Comment: Use `setScrollableY(false)` with the solution above. Also make sure the width of the celll is set to 100.