# Webbrowser blank on android

Tags: android, codenameone

I'm using a Webbroswer component to display some HTML file stored on the device. I was finally able to display it properly. But I've a remaining problem on android : the Webbrowser is displayed but it's filled with blank.

But if I click on it, it then display the correct content!

I've try to use some revalidate(), forceRevalidate(), requestFocus() calls and thinks like that but I couldn't solve the problem. Any idea?

Comment: show code not just method names

Comment: Change the device and try other device.

Comment: I'll try later with another device and see if it works, but there will be always a problem on my phone...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use :

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

if( wb.getInternal() instanceof BrowserComponent )
{
    BrowserComponent bc = (BrowserComponent) wb.getInternal();
    bc.setPinchToZoomEnabled( true );
}

wb.setPage( textToDisplay, "" );

findModuleDetailsContainer( currentContainer ).addComponent( BorderLayout.CENTER, wb );

Form currentForm = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
currentForm.forceRevalidate();
```

And then I've tried to add some `revalidate()` on webbrowser and its container, but nothing work:

```
wb.revalidate();
findModuleDetailsContainer( currentContainer ).revalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

there is some problem in webbrowser's style so changes its bg color to other color as shown in below codes

```
    webbrowser.getAllStyle().setBgColor(0x55ff0000);
    webbrowser.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0x5500ff00);
```

and when the content is displayed chanage its bg color as per you needs.

Answer (score 0):

The [WebBrowser](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/WebBrowser.html)/[BrowserComponent](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html) need to be in the center of a border layout in a Form or in a layout similar to the one described here: [Using two WebBrowsers on codename one (layout management)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462693/using-two-webbrowsers-on-codename-one-layout-management)

The reason for this is simple, the HTML is loaded asynchronously by the native browser rendering engine. While it's loading the browser has no "preferred size" hence it will get sized to 0. Notice that even if your HTML is local to the device this will be running in an asynchronous thread!

Update:

Trying to reproduce your issue I did this which worked fine on my OPO device.

```
    Form hi = new Form("Tab Test", new BorderLayout());
    Tabs tb = new Tabs();
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tb);
    BrowserComponent bc = new BrowserComponent();
    bc.setURL("https://www.codenameone.com/");
    tb.addTab("First", bc);
    tb.addTab("Second", new Label("Dummy"));
    hi.show();
```

[image: Screenshot from OPO]

Comment: Yes that what I've done and I have no problem to display it correctly (now). The only problem is that it is filled with white color after loading, then if I click on it, it display the content.

Comment: FYI you should edit your question with additional information and not post addition "answers". To notify us of new edits you should post a comment to the answer. I just tried this on the device and it worked for me. Editing my answer with sample code similar to yours.